# how to set the list of executable functions python?

Tags: python

I have a list of functions that I am running.

```
def main():
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
    func4()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Today I'm running function1, tomorrow I'll run function2 and function3
How should the script accept from the user a list of values by which it will launch these functions?

It seems to me that I hurried with the question and seemed to find a solution.
i use ready module **console-menu**
https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems to me that I hurried with the question and seemed to find a solution.
i use ready module console-menu
https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `argparse` builtin library
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

```py
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Simple Title")
    parser.add_argument(
        "function1", action="store_true", help="function1",
    )
    # include more flags here

    args = parser.parse_args()  # parse arguments
    # option to do more validation here
    return args

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    if args.function1:
        function1()
    if argsfunction1:
        function2()
```

You would then simply call with the flags you want

```bash
% python ./myscripy.py --function1
output from function 1
```

Comment: I would like to do select functions directly in the terminal